# Make boot parameters permanent on live session itself?

Tags: command-line, grub2, kernel, juju, gedit

Live usb with 4gb persistent.
I follow these steps:-

1. I press **e** on grub2 at Boot.
2. I add **pci=nomsi** at the end of quiet splash. Its effects works perfectly.
3. To make it permanent i then in terminal and type this command-

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
4. I make these changes in the text file

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
   ```

I get these in terminal after that-

```
(gedit:5013): WARNING: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported
(gedit:5013): WARNING: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported
(gedit:5013): WARNING: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported    
(gedit:5013): WARNING: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported
(gedit:5013): WARNING: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported
(gedit:5013): WARNING: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

5. Then in terminal i type-

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Everythings works fine but it doest load with that boot parameter next time i do a reboot.

**EDIT :-**
I tried these two seperate method also and they have issue of there own. 
LINK - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycmNz.png)

1. **Boot repair** - It just doest open.

   2.**grub-crustomizer** - 
   NOte- I also added device.map manually but what to do with grub.cfg now.

[image]

[image]

**I want to add boot parameter(pci=nomsi) permanently by which ever method works.**
Thanks,

---

So after trying `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. I see this after every fresh boot.[image]

**Despite** that, effects of `pci=nomsi` are not taking place and system  is not booted with that parameter.
How do i know that?
Because when i type this command- `cat /proc/cmdline`

there is no (pci=nomis) at the end of quite splash.
Pic - [image]

Comment: Please re-do it using `nano` text editor.. before proceeding are you familiar with `nano`?

Comment: NO. How should i proceed now?

Comment: Let me post an answer so you can follow

Comment: Wait!! I have tried this before - `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Comment: And what happened then

Comment: I didnt know what to do after that. I will follow your answer and post back asap.

Comment: And also look at the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1575484) on that gedit issue your having.

Answer (score 2):

Please re-edit that document and this time use `nano` text editor.

How to use `nano`:

1. Open the document in question:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Do the edit re-move that entry you made and re-add it again:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
   ```
3. Now save the file with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Close `nano` with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
5. Now update grub: `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot your system

Comment: "booted with that parameter" please explain?

Comment: With or without that parameter is the parameter entry not seen in that file after reboot?

Comment: Sorry, its wihout that parameter. I also added an answer, it will make some sense now. Thanks again, its my very time touching a linux OS. Please understand.

Comment: @Jason did this issue start after you first tried to change `grub` using that `grub customizer`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed this issue.
In my case, I had 2 Linux operating systems installed. One was Ubuntu and the other was Kali.

In fact, I almost had the same issue that you were facing. (i.e: I was not able to add kernal boot parameters(pci=nomsi) permanently)

The mistake that I did was I tried executing all the commands to add boot parameters to Ubuntu from Ubuntu itself. But unfortunately, the bootloader was installed by Kali Linux. Hence all the changes that I made from Ubuntu were not reflected in Kali's bootloader.

**Fix:**

1.Boot the operating system which installed the bootloader.(In my case it was Kali)

2.From a terminal run:

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

3.Under the menuentry of your operating system(to which you want to add the boot parameter) find the line starting with linux and add the boot parameter(`pci=nomsi`) to the end of it. For Ubuntu, after adding the parameter that line should look something like this:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic root=UUID=22aca2b7-9520-4c80-925b-10bde01378d5 ro  quiet splash pci=nomsi $vt_handoff
```

4.Now save the file and close it.

5.Finally, update grub: `sudo update-grub`